# Finding the set of all linear combinations of vectors in S on [0,1]

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I want to find < S > or the set of all linear combinations of vectors in S of exactly [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882995/how-to-show-that-the-set-of-functions-1-x-x2-x3-is-linearly-independent) on [0,1].

$$ S = \{1, ,^2,^3,...,^,...\} $$

F (the field) is R.

I read [the theorem from the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVQrz.png) that I have, but I really don't understand it.

What would be the approach to find them?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In this case the linear combinations of $S$ are the polynomials in one variable.

Comment: @s.harp So you mean all of members of S are the linear combinations?! how do you say that?

Comment: @hardmath Sorry, I just edited the post. Field is real numbers

Comment: It is easy to see that any polynomial lies in the span. If you take an element in the span, it must be the linear combination of a finite number of elements hence a polynomial.